# Django-axes Errors: 'Settings' object has no attribute . .

Tags: python, django, web, django-authentication, django-settings

I've run into a lot of attribute errors when using django-axes. Whenever I fix one of them by setting the default attributes, more start showing up. I followed the documentation for installation. Here is my code...

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for ChatTest project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
import django

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
if('SECRET_KEY' in os.environ):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]
if('SECRET_KEY' not in os.environ):
    SECRET_KEY = 'o1(-!s0um*rj47xv8vk@)pdq3)2c1o-et!v!rnqq3p4m(9592k'               #Secret key I use for local development 

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.railway.app','localhost', '127.0.0.1']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
    'Chat.apps.ChatConfig',
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
    'axes',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'axes.middleware.AxesMiddleware',
]
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ChatTest.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ChatTest.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'ChatTest.routing.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

if('PGDATABASE' in os.environ):
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ["PGDATABASE"],
            'USER': os.environ["PGUSER"],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ["PGPASSWORD"],
            'HOST': os.environ["PGHOST"],
            'PORT': os.environ["PGPORT"],
        }
    }
if('PGDATABASE' not in os.environ):
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Chat.Account'


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Prague'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

if('REDIS_URL' in os.environ):
    CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
        "default": {
            "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
            "CONFIG": {
                "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')],
            },
        },
    }
    CACHES = {
        "default": {
            "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
            "LOCATION": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')],
            "OPTIONS": {
                "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient"
            }
        }
    }
if('REDIS_URL' not in os.environ):
    CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # AxesBackend should be the first backend in the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS list.
    'axes.backends.AxesBackend',

    # Django ModelBackend is the default authentication backend.
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]


SION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False  # Default: False - Store CSRF token in Session as opposed to in cookie
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False 

SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True

AXES_ENABLED = True 
AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT = 3  
AXES_LOCK_OUT_AT_FAILURE = True
AXES_COOLOFF_TIME = 0.1         # in hours   - now set to 6 mins

AXES_LOCKOUT_CALLABLE = "Chat.views.lockout"

AXES_USERNAME_FORM_FIELD = "username"
AXES_USERNAME_CALLABLE = None
AXES_PROXY_ORDER = "left-most"
AXES_PROXY_COUNT = None
AXES_PROXY_TRUSTED_IPS = None
AXES_ONLY_WHITELIST = False
AXES_WHITELIST_CALLABLE = None
AXES_LOCK_OUT_BY_USER_OR_IP = False

AXES_META_PRECEDENCE_ORDER = [
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    'REMOTE_ADDR',
]

django.setup()
```

At the bottom I tried to set some of the default attributes that were causing errors. Right now, the code above results in a `'Settings' object has no attribute 'AXES_HANDLER'` error.

In **views.py** when authenticating the user I have set `request=request` as the documentation said. I've also added a lockout function:

```
def lockout(request, credentials, *args, **kwargs):
    messages.error(request, "Account locked. Try again in 6 minutes")
    return redirect('index')
```

Note: I am also using a custom user model so users can log in with their email. I tested it on a different project with django-axes and everything was working well. So I don't think that's the issue here.

**Question**: How do I fix this? Is there anything I need to install or configure differently?

Comment: Yes I have and setting ```AXES_HANDLER = True``` results in 'bool' object has no attribute 'rsplit' error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I am also using django-axes for custom views.py login page. What I did was to include decorator `@axes_dispatch` on my login function. For Settings.py, ensure that `AXES_USERNAME_FORM_FIELD` is configured to your user credential field. For mine, im using 'email'. So its should be changed to `AXES_USERNAME_FORM_FIELD='email'`.

```
from axes.decorators import axes_dispatch

views.py

@axes_dispatch
def user_login(request):
...

settings.py
AXES_USERNAME_FORM_FIELD='email'
```

Comment: I still get the same errors when trying this, but thank you for your answer. I hope your solution will work for other people :d

Comment: I will accept your answer because I haven't seen this approach anywhere and it seems the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to your `settings.py` file:

```
AXES_HANDLER = 'axes.handlers.database.AxesDatabaseHandler'
```

Comment: I get a ```Module "axes.handlers.database" does not define a "AxesDatabaseHandler" attribute/class``` error

Comment: I just feel like something isn't installed properely

Comment: @IceSpeaker have you installed it to venv? `pip install django-axes`

Comment: I do have it install globally and it worked in a different project so I have no idea :/

Comment: Don't do that. Always use venv. Using global environment is very risky on many levels.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by adding basically every option there is:

```
AXES_ENABLED = True 
AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT = 3  
AXES_LOCK_OUT_AT_FAILURE = True
AXES_COOLOFF_TIME = 0.1         # in hours   - now set to 6 mins

AXES_LOCKOUT_CALLABLE = "Chat.views.lockout"

AXES_PROXY_ORDER = "left-most"
AXES_PROXY_COUNT = None
AXES_PROXY_TRUSTED_IPS = None
AXES_ONLY_WHITELIST = False
AXES_ONLY_ADMIN_SITE = False
AXES_ONLY_USER_FAILURES = False
AXES_ENABLE_ADMIN= True
AXES_LOCK_OUT_BY_COMBINATION_USER_AND_IP= False
AXES_LOCK_OUT_BY_USER_OR_IP= False
AXES_USE_USER_AGENT= False 
AXES_CACHE='axes'
AXES_LOCKOUT_TEMPLATE=None
AXES_LOCKOUT_URL=None
AXES_VERBOSE=True
AXES_USERNAME_FORM_FIELD='username'
AXES_USERNAME_CALLABLE=None
AXES_WHITELIST_CALLABLE=None
AXES_PASSWORD_FORM_FIELD='password'
AXES_SENSITIVE_PARAMETERS=[]
AXES_NEVER_LOCKOUT_GET=False
AXES_NEVER_LOCKOUT_WHITELIST=False
AXES_IP_BLACKLIST=None
AXES_IP_WHITELIST=None
AXES_DISABLE_ACCESS_LOG=False
AXES_ENABLE_ACCESS_FAILURE_LOG=True
AXES_ACCESS_FAILURE_LOG_PER_USER_LIMIT=1000
AXES_RESET_ON_SUCCESS=False
AXES_ALLOWED_CORS_ORIGINS='*'
AXES_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE=403
AXES_RESET_COOL_OFF_ON_FAILURE_DURING_LOCKOUT=True
AXES_CLIENT_STR_CALLABLE=None
AXES_COOLOFF_MESSAGE=None

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyMemcacheCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    },
    'axes': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}

AXES_META_PRECEDENCE_ORDER = [
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    'REMOTE_ADDR',
]

AXES_HANDLER = 'axes.handlers.database.AxesDatabaseHandler'
```

If anyone comes up with a better approach, please post it here.